# Using /test#test within Html.ActionLink()

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Example:

I have a web page www.test.com/ and then if I click a link, e.g. `<a href="#test">` then the page will jump to wherever the element with ID 'test'. Is it possible to implement the same thing within an Html.ActionLink(). Obviously, I could keep the same format, but when navigating between pages with a #id I need it to work too.

So I'm looking for something where I can put `Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", "Controller", "id")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the fragment parameter:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
  this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
  string linkText,
  string actionName,
  string controllerName,
  string protocol,
  string hostName,
  string fragment,
  Object routeValues,
  Object htmlAttributes
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522.aspx

Comment: Ah thanks that's brilliant. I did look there but I didn't know it was referred to as an anchor.